# Add a logo to a leaflet map in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shinyjs

I would like to add a logo to a leaflet map in a shiny app.

The `addLogo` function of the `leafem` package allows this, when I generate a map outside the shiny environment the function works perfectly, however, when applying the function in shiny it does not work.

I do not know what I can be obviating or if there is another way to do it.

```
├── app.R
└── www
    └── Logo.png
```

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(leafem)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  leafletOutput("map")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({    
    
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = -79.442471,
              lat = 43.6857,
              zoom = 12) %>%
      addLogo("Logo.png",
              src= "local")    
    
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `src= "remote"` in `addLogo`. Even though the Shiny app and image is in your local computer, you need to use it as `remote`. Using local will point to `../graphs/Logo.png` instead of only `Logo.png` (that is the default for files under the `www` directory).

```R
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(leafem)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  leafletOutput("map")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({    
    
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = -79.442471,
              lat = 43.6857,
              zoom = 12) %>%
      addLogo("Logo.png",
              src= "remote")    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks!! I don't know how I didn't try before ...

Comment: I'm coming back here a couple years later... and this example doesn't work for me.

I copy and pasted the code, with the same file structure the OP describes, and I get box showing the logo not loading on my leaflet.

I can get the logo displayed outside of the shiny context with src='local'